# flying saucer pdf from url with parameters

Tags: jsf, flying-saucer

i have successfully rendered my index page to PDFs, following documentation from the internet, however i couldn't do it with URL having parameters, as below

```
index.xhtml?id=321&loc=us
```

it returns error, how to do convert to PDF from this url

Comment: Please mind the error.

Comment: I think @Tiny means _Please **mention** the error_

Comment: the error is near the renderer.setDocument() method, "stream closed", it occurs only when i add the params to the url, otherwise ok

Comment: in my xhtml page, i have <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> tags, which accepts the params and generating datatable rows

Answer (score 0):

The & character is not valid in HTML. You should replace it with &amp;.

So `index.xhtml?id=321&loc=us` should be replaced with `index.xhtml?id=321&amp;loc=us`.